# what is this error in openerp?

Tags: odoo

how to fix this error ?

> CRITICAL mydb2 openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module exp_edit
>   CRITICAL mydb2 openerp.modules.module: unindent does not match any
>
> outer indentation level (hredit.py, line 61)

my py file code is as follows where the line is mentioned

```
def onchange_employee_id(self, cr, uid, ids, employee_id, context=None):
    emp_obj = self.pool.get('hr.employee')
    first = False
    if employee_id:
            employee = emp_obj.browse(cr, uid, employee_id, context=context)
            first = employee.first.id
    return {'value': {'first': first}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do some research before asking question. It is just a python indentation error paste this code.

```
def onchange_employee_id(self, cr, uid, ids, employee_id, context=None):
    emp_obj = self.pool.get('hr.employee')
    first = False
    if employee_id:
        employee = emp_obj.browse(cr, uid, employee_id, context=context)  //unindent this line
        first = employee.first.id
    return {'value': {'first': first}}
```

Comment: I had done the research and also issue was solved  two days back itself, i knew it is just a indent problem, but it wasnt getting sorted out, thanks for the reply

Comment: i have solved problems like this before, but this one took slightly longer time, that's it,